# How to inspect task logs in Spark local mode

Tags: r, apache-spark, logging, sparklyr

I'm using a local Spark instance through the `sparklyr` R package on a 64G RAM 40 core machine.

I have to process thousands of text files and parse email addresses in them. The goal is to have a data frame with columns such as user name, top level domain, domain, subdomain(s). The data frame is then saved as Parquet file. I split up the files in batches of 2.5G each and process each batch separately.

Most of the batches work fine, however, from time to time, a task fails and the whole batch is "gone". This is the output from the log in such a case:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 47 in stage 2260.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 47.0 in stage 2260.0 (TID 112228, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$2: (string) => array<string>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.project_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.util.random.SamplingUtils$.reservoirSampleAndCount(SamplingUtils.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner$$anonfun$13.apply(Partitioner.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner$$anonfun$13.apply(Partitioner.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:853)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:853)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1283)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:309)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:229)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1093)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1206)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1273)
    at scala.util.matching.Regex.split(Regex.scala:526)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$2.apply(Tokenizer.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$2.apply(Tokenizer.scala:141)
    ... 22 more
```

I use `FTRegexTokenizer` quite often, e.g. here to split email address into username and domains:

```
spark_tbls_separated %<>%
ft_regex_tokenizer(input_col = "email",
                         output_col = "email_split",
                         pattern = "@",
                         to_lower_case = FALSE) %>%
      sdf_separate_column(column = "email_split",
                          into = c("email_user", "email_domain")) %>%
      select(-email_split, -email)
```

So now I'd like to know which Spark transformation *exactly* causes the error, and for which type of input data it fails, so I can actually debug the cause of the error. I guess the only way to figure this out is to look at task logs (do they even exist?). Ideally I could look at the log of task 47 and get way more detailed logging info. How can I access these on a local machine?

Here are my configuration options, so e.g. a history server is prepared to run:

```
spark_config <- spark_config()
spark_config$`sparklyr.shell.driver-memory` <- "64G"
spark_config$spark.memory.fraction <- 0.75
spark_config$spark.speculation <- TRUE
spark_config$spark.speculation.multiplier <- 2
spark_config$spark.speculation.quantile <- 0.5
spark_config$sparklyr.backend.timeout <- 3600 * 2 # two-hour timeout
spark_config$spark.eventLog.enabled <- TRUE
spark_config$spark.eventLog.dir <- "file:///tmp/spark-events"
spark_config$spark.history.fs.logDirectory  <- "file:///tmp/spark-events"

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", config = spark_config)
```

**Note that this question is not about the actual error seen here, it is about the possibility of inspecting the task log to figure out at which line my `sparklyr` script fails**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sparklyr split string (to string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522707/sparklyr-split-string-to-string)

Comment: In general this is  as detailed as Spark log can get - it tells you exactly which component, at which line and for what reason, failed (ditto). Short of attaching remote Java debugger, you won't get more information.

Comment: Okay.. but that means I won't have a way to figure it out which `FTRegexTokenizer` call actually causes the error?

Comment: And also, regarding the other question you linked too: Why is `FTRegexTokenizer` not suited there? Because there are NAs in column `A`, and `split` can handle this? So would you suggest using `split` as well here, in my case?

Comment: ML `Tokenizer` is specifically intended for text processing so API wise it doesn't make much sense here (not to mention it doesn't allow you to detect different data quality issues), and due to its usage of UDF, it doesn't provide the same opportunity for optimization. As of the former question I am not sure what you mean by by _which_.  If you think about scenario where multiple tokenizers are present in a single pipeline, then I'd start with Spark Web UI.

Comment: Yes, I have a scenario with multiple tokenizers happening one after another. So you say by looking at the failed task(s) in Spark Web UI I can figure out at which tokenizer it failed? If yes, how to do so?

Comment: If these are chained, then UI might not help you, as all should be placed in the same stage. In such case the only option is either JVM debugger or just elimination until you determine the failing one.